# Giving the even, odd, and zeros from a given number

Tags: java

Could anyone help me out with this programming problem for my comp sci class? I need to write an application that will read a number given by the user and then print the number of odd and even numbers and the number of zeros. This is what I have so far. When a number is entered I get an excessive amount of even digits continually.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//3.6
int value;
int num = 0;
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int zero = 0;

System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
value = scan.nextInt();

while(value >= 0)
{
    num = (value % 10);

    if(num % 2 == 0)
    {

         even++;
    }
    else if(num % 2 != 0)
    {

        odd++;
    }
    else if(num == 0)
    {

         zero++;
    }

    value = value/10;
    System.out.println("even numbers: " + even);
    System.out.println("odd numbers: " + odd);
    System.out.println("zeros: " + zero);
}
```

Comment: When num is zero, num % 2 would equal 0, so you would get zero incorrectly counting as even.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `while(value >= 0)` to `while(value > 0)` and reorder your `if..else if` statement as follow:

```
if(num == 0)
{
     zero++;
}
else if(num % 2 == 0)
{
     even++;
}
else if(num % 2 != 0)
{
    odd++;
}
```

In this way you can count also the zeros. (consider that `0%2 == 0`)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(value >= 0){

        num = (value % 10);

        if(num == 0)
        {
            zero++;
             break;
        }
        else if(num % 2 != 0)
        {

            odd++;
        }
        else if(num % 2 == 0)
        {

             even++;
        }

        value = value/10;

    }
    System.out.println("even numbers: " + even);
    System.out.println("odd numbers: " + odd);
    System.out.println("zeros: " + zero);
   }
```

Writing the code like this provides an output like:

```
Please enter a number.
512222

even numbers: 4
odd numbers: 2
zeros: 1
```

Comment: This goes to an infinite loop. Try it with 100

Comment: I tried, the result was `zero: 1` end then it ended succesfully

Comment: didn't see the break

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solutions that works:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //3.6
    int value;
    int num = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    int zero = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
    value = scan.nextInt();
    char[] charValue = String.valueOf(value).toCharArray();

    for (char c: charValue) {
        num = Character.getNumericValue(c);

        if (num == 0) {

            zero++;
        }else if (num % 2 == 0) {

            even++;
        } else {
            odd++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("even numbers: " + even);
    System.out.println("odd numbers: " + odd);
    System.out.println("zeros: " + zero);
```